# Plotting more than one linear regression line in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, linear-regression

I am trying to plot, using ggplot, a series of scatter plots with regression lines for several datasets. I started with the following dataset, "onepectCO2MEDIAN". The data for this dataset is as follows:

```
onepctCO2MEDIAN
                x          y
layer.1   0.000000000  0.0000000
layer.2   0.006794447  4.9002490
layer.3   0.014288058  0.1608000
layer.4   0.022087920  6.6349133
layer.5   0.030797357 -1.2429506
layer.6   0.038451072  1.5643374
layer.7   0.048087904 -2.2659035
layer.8   0.058677729  2.2070045
layer.9   0.069261406 -2.3677001
layer.10  0.080524530 -1.0913506
layer.11  0.092760246  0.4099940
layer.12  0.103789609 -0.1259727
layer.13  0.116953168 -2.4138253
layer.14  0.129253298  7.0890257
layer.15  0.141710050 -0.7593539
layer.16  0.156002052  0.0454416
layer.17  0.170648172 -1.5349683
layer.18  0.185318425  6.5524201
layer.19  0.199463055 -0.8312563
layer.20  0.213513337 -2.5099183
layer.21  0.228839271  0.1365968
layer.22  0.246981293 -1.3719845
layer.23  0.263012767 -0.8712988
layer.24  0.278505564  0.6632584
layer.25  0.293658361  0.7938036
layer.26  0.310747266  3.4880637
layer.27  0.325990349 -4.4612208
layer.28  0.342517540  0.0871734
layer.29  0.362751633 -1.4171578
layer.30  0.380199537 -0.9956508
layer.31  0.394992948  0.3215526
layer.32  0.414373398  3.1403866
layer.33  0.430690214 -0.7376099
layer.34  0.449738145 -2.4860541
layer.35  0.470167458 -3.4235858
layer.36  0.489019871  0.4824748
layer.37  0.507242471 -0.9785386
layer.38  0.524314284  8.5359684
layer.39  0.543750525  5.4844742
layer.40  0.564234197  3.2149367
layer.41  0.583679616  3.9168916 
layer.42  0.601459444  4.4907020
layer.43  0.619924664  6.5410410
layer.44  0.639932007  4.8068650
layer.45  0.661347181  8.1510170
layer.46  0.684117317  0.2697413
layer.47  0.704829752 -0.1807501
layer.48  0.725045770  9.7181249
layer.49  0.745165825  1.5406466
layer.50  0.765016139 -1.6476041
layer.51  0.783461511  4.8024603
layer.52  0.806382924  4.0421516
layer.53  0.829241335  9.3756512
layer.54  0.849924415  5.3305050
layer.55  0.871352434  7.5445803
layer.56  0.893632233  6.4679547
layer.57  0.916052133  2.8096065
layer.58  0.938579470  5.3921661
layer.59  0.959907651  7.2043689
layer.60  0.981643587  3.3350806
layer.61  1.004116774  8.8690707
layer.62  1.028363466  1.7861299
layer.63  1.054009140  6.2555038
layer.64  1.072440803  7.6079236
layer.65  1.094457805  7.6871483
layer.66  1.123176277  4.7787764
layer.67  1.149430871 12.7110502
layer.68  1.170912921 -0.7156284
layer.69  1.196743071  1.6490899
layer.70  1.218625903  3.0363024
layer.71  1.241868377  4.2974769
layer.72  1.267941594  1.9543778
layer.73  1.290708780  3.9986964
layer.74  1.313222289  4.5179472
layer.75  1.339045882  0.9337905
layer.76  1.362803459  3.3050770
layer.77  1.384450197  3.5422970
layer.78  1.409720302  5.9973660
layer.79  1.435851157  0.5081869
layer.80  1.455592215  7.9661630
layer.81  1.479495347  9.9460496
layer.82  1.506051958  3.7908372
layer.83  1.525728464  2.5735847
layer.84  1.549362063 10.1404974
layer.85  1.573440671 13.7408304
layer.86  1.600278735  0.9335771
layer.87  1.623879492  9.7588742
layer.88  1.650029302  1.2769395
layer.89  1.672362328 13.4970906
layer.90  1.700221121 10.2087502
layer.91  1.724793375  1.6811275
layer.92  1.751070559  6.1178992
layer.93  1.778022110 -0.1567626
layer.94  1.803022087  3.8237479
layer.95  1.830668867  4.4331468
layer.96  1.855736911  5.9790707
layer.97  1.882615030 11.3104333
layer.98  1.909218490  8.2142607
layer.99  1.938130021 15.3209674
layer.100 1.963727593  5.8178217
layer.101 1.993271947  9.6004907
layer.102 2.022548139  3.4063646
layer.103 2.050679922  4.7375010
layer.104 2.078064442  3.0133019
layer.105 2.104113460  5.5659522
layer.106 2.133597612 12.0346333
layer.107 2.164026260 -0.4028320
layer.108 2.194852829 10.5996780
layer.109 2.224257946  5.4479584
layer.110 2.252194643  4.7052374
layer.111 2.277335048 14.0962019
layer.112 2.304058313  5.7149016
layer.113 2.330930233  3.7780072
layer.114 2.357022762  4.4120620
layer.115 2.386489272  4.1866085
layer.116 2.417503953  6.9078802
layer.117 2.448524356  2.7825739
layer.118 2.478698969  7.6171786
layer.119 2.510175705 10.2410603
layer.120 2.539697886  8.1820711
layer.121 2.567915559  4.8275494
layer.122 2.597463250 19.1624883
layer.123 2.627518773 16.0677109
layer.124 2.658759236 12.5897081
layer.125 2.692401528  9.2907988
layer.126 2.721903205  7.4262502
layer.127 2.753021359  9.3902518
layer.128 2.786313415 12.6193550
layer.129 2.819564104 11.1121040
layer.130 2.850823164 15.7907100
layer.131 2.880394101 10.7425287
layer.132 2.911391258  7.7971430
layer.133 2.942965150  8.8060858
layer.134 2.974468350 17.5606266
layer.135 3.008983612 17.3088605
layer.136 3.040015221 13.4500543
layer.137 3.072668672 14.6377884
layer.138 3.105982423  8.0798552
```

dput(onepctCO2MEDIAN)

```
dput(onepctCO2MEDIAN)
structure(list(x = c(0, 0.00679444684647024, 0.014288058038801, 
0.0220879195258021, 0.0307973567396402,0.0384510718286037,0.0480879042297602, 
0.0586777292191982, 0.0692614056169987, 0.080524530261755,0.0927602462470531, 
0.103789608925581, 0.116953168064356, 0.129253298044205, 0.141710050404072, 
0.156002052128315, 0.170648172497749, 0.185318425297737, 0.199463054537773, 
0.21351333707571, 0.22883927077055, 0.246981292963028, 0.263012766838074, 
0.278505563735962, 0.29365836083889, 0.310747265815735, 0.325990349054337, 
0.342517539858818, 0.362751632928848, 0.380199536681175, 0.39499294757843, 
0.414373397827148, 0.430690214037895, 0.449738144874573, 0.470167458057404, 
0.489019870758057, 0.507242470979691, 0.524314284324646, 0.543750524520874, 
0.56423419713974, 0.583679616451263, 0.601459443569183, 0.619924664497375, 
0.639932006597519, 0.661347180604935, 0.684117317199707, 0.704829752445221, 
0.725045770406723, 0.745165824890137, 0.765016138553619, 0.783461511135101, 
0.806382924318314, 0.829241335391998, 0.84992441534996, 0.871352434158325, 
0.893632233142853, 0.916052132844925, 0.938579469919205, 0.959907650947571, 
0.981643587350845, 1.00411677360535, 1.02836346626282, 1.05400913953781, 
1.07244080305099, 1.09445780515671, 1.12317627668381, 1.14943087100983, 
1.17091292142868, 1.19674307107925, 1.21862590312958, 1.24186837673187, 
1.26794159412384, 1.2907087802887, 1.31322228908539, 1.33904588222504, 
1.36280345916748, 1.38445019721985, 1.40972030162811, 1.43585115671158, 
1.45559221506119, 1.47949534654617, 1.50605195760727, 1.52572846412659, 
1.5493620634079, 1.5734406709671, 1.60027873516083, 1.62387949228287, 
1.65002930164337, 1.67236232757568, 1.70022112131119, 1.72479337453842, 
1.75107055902481, 1.77802211046219, 1.80302208662033, 1.83066886663437, 
1.85573691129684, 1.88261502981186, 1.90921849012375, 1.93813002109528, 
1.96372759342194, 1.99327194690704, 2.02254813909531, 2.05067992210388, 
2.07806444168091, 2.1041134595871, 2.13359761238098, 2.16402626037598, 
2.19485282897949, 2.2242579460144, 2.25219464302063, 2.27733504772186, 
2.30405831336975, 2.33093023300171, 2.35702276229858, 2.38648927211761, 
2.41750395298004, 2.44852435588837, 2.47869896888733, 2.51017570495605, 
2.53969788551331, 2.567915558815, 2.59746325016022, 2.62751877307892, 
2.65875923633575, 2.69240152835846, 2.72190320491791, 2.75302135944366, 
2.78631341457367, 2.8195641040802, 2.85082316398621, 2.88039410114288, 
2.91139125823975, 2.94296514987946, 2.97446835041046, 3.00898361206055, 
3.04001522064209, 3.07266867160797, 3.10598242282867), y = c(0, 
4.90024901723162, 0.160799993152722, 6.63491326258641, -1.24295055804536, 
1.56433744259162, -2.26590352245208, 2.20700446463354, -2.36770012911069, 
-1.09135061899174, 0.409993989292701, -0.125972681525582, -2.41382533818026, 
7.08902570153028, -0.759353880417294, 0.0454415959640926, -1.53496826259972, 
6.55242014096194, -0.831256280861552, -2.50991825629084, 0.136596820654013, 
-1.37198445498419, -0.871298832596736, 0.663258363762466, 0.793803634291308, 
3.48806373666998, -4.46122081238949, 0.0871733966938564, -1.41715777257774, 
-0.995650815648318, 0.32155262317503, 3.14038657369241, -0.737609879885404, 
-2.48605406511292, -3.423585843908, 0.482474753780281, -0.978538630093809, 
8.53596837794201, 5.48447420320695, 3.21493665820644, 3.91689160157513, 
4.49070195980797, 6.54104103157039, 4.80686500146557, 8.15101701282067, 
0.26974132191657, -0.180750068063062, 9.71812491230244, 1.54064657400204, 
-1.64760408795688, 4.80246028991894, 4.04215159914344, 9.37565121768513, 
5.33050496938428, 7.54458026088508, 6.46795470819342, 2.80960651433971, 
5.39216613235986, 7.20436888038562, 3.3350806460997, 8.86907069895943, 
1.78612988613659, 6.25550382050395, 7.60792364896564, 7.68714830528144, 
4.77877638957615, 12.7110501777314, -0.715628443181046, 1.64908991824022, 
3.03630240714679, 4.29747688442346, 1.95437780501881, 3.99869636910933, 
4.51794724689848, 0.933790484492299, 3.30507700050003, 3.5422970157433, 
5.99736597322524, 0.508186860060022, 7.96616300581067, 9.94604963036295, 
3.79083717222623, 2.57358468532258, 10.1404974171776, 13.7408303595752, 
0.933577123801399, 9.75887417074129, 1.27693947132921, 13.4970905965787, 
10.2087501765735, 1.68112753028756, 6.1178991508927, -0.156762622680077, 
3.82374791691426, 4.43314678736265, 5.97907067167507, 11.3104332518482, 
8.21426074201525, 15.320967360602, 5.81782169471483, 9.6004907412354, 
3.40636455909704, 4.73750103921864, 3.0133019468806, 5.56595224859066, 
12.0346332527215, -0.40283199827104, 10.5996779538754, 5.44795836991128, 
4.70523736412729, 14.096201892183, 5.71490161813391, 3.77800720810782, 
4.41206200639436, 4.18660847858423, 6.90788020044911, 2.78257393345915, 
7.61717857379431, 10.2410602647684, 8.18207106836167, 4.82754943871433, 
19.1624882857155, 16.0677109398509, 12.589708067017, 9.29079879799404, 
7.42625019725314, 9.39025179806185, 12.6193550331438, 11.1121039747257, 
15.7907099734986, 10.7425286789233, 7.79714300307344, 8.80608578166101, 
17.5606266346039, 17.3088604929222, 13.4500543478523, 14.6377884248645, 
8.07985518296064)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("layer.1", 
"layer.2", "layer.3", "layer.4", "layer.5", "layer.6", "layer.7", 
"layer.8", "layer.9", "layer.10", "layer.11", "layer.12", "layer.13", 
"layer.14", "layer.15", "layer.16", "layer.17", "layer.18", "layer.19", 
"layer.20", "layer.21", "layer.22", "layer.23", "layer.24", "layer.25", 
"layer.26", "layer.27", "layer.28", "layer.29", "layer.30", "layer.31", 
"layer.32", "layer.33", "layer.34", "layer.35", "layer.36", "layer.37", 
"layer.38", "layer.39", "layer.40", "layer.41", "layer.42", "layer.43", 
"layer.44", "layer.45", "layer.46", "layer.47", "layer.48", "layer.49", 
"layer.50", "layer.51", "layer.52", "layer.53", "layer.54", "layer.55", 
"layer.56", "layer.57", "layer.58", "layer.59", "layer.60", "layer.61", 
"layer.62", "layer.63", "layer.64", "layer.65", "layer.66", "layer.67", 
"layer.68", "layer.69", "layer.70", "layer.71", "layer.72", "layer.73", 
"layer.74", "layer.75", "layer.76", "layer.77", "layer.78", "layer.79", 
"layer.80", "layer.81", "layer.82", "layer.83", "layer.84", "layer.85", 
"layer.86", "layer.87", "layer.88", "layer.89", "layer.90", "layer.91", 
"layer.92", "layer.93", "layer.94", "layer.95", "layer.96", "layer.97", 
"layer.98", "layer.99", "layer.100", "layer.101", "layer.102", 
"layer.103", "layer.104", "layer.105", "layer.106", "layer.107", 
"layer.108", "layer.109", "layer.110", "layer.111", "layer.112", 
"layer.113", "layer.114", "layer.115", "layer.116", "layer.117", 
"layer.118", "layer.119", "layer.120", "layer.121", "layer.122", 
"layer.123", "layer.124", "layer.125", "layer.126", "layer.127", 
"layer.128", "layer.129", "layer.130", "layer.131", "layer.132", 
"layer.133", "layer.134", "layer.135", "layer.136", "layer.137", 
"layer.138"))
```

I started with the following to generate the first regression line and scatter plot:

```
lm<-ggplot(onepctCO2MEDIAN) +  
geom_jitter(aes(RCP1pctCO2cumulativeMedian[1:138], departurea),   
colour="blue") + geom_smooth(aes(RCP1pctCO2cumulativeMedian[1:138], 
departurea), method=lm)
```

But I receive this error:

```
Warning message:
Computation failed in `stat_smooth()`:
'what' must be a function or character string
```

A blue scatter plot is successfully generated, but the problem is that the regression line does not appear, presumably related to the above warning.

Is there a reason for this? I would appreciate any assistance!

Comment: You have a lot of unknown variables in your code. Try to show us how you came from the dataset to those variables. Also, if you want us to be able to use your dataset you could consider using `dput(onepctCO2MEDIAN)`. This will give us a command we can run to reproduce your dataset.

Comment: @dylanvanw Thank you for your response - I just added the dput(onepctCO2MEDIAN) above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get a scatter plot with a regression line by doing the following:

```r
library(tidyverse)
#> Registered S3 methods overwritten by 'ggplot2':
#>   method         from 
#>   [.quosures     rlang
#>   c.quosures     rlang
#>   print.quosures rlang

onepctCO2MEDIAN <- structure(list(x = c(0, 0.00679444684647024, 0.014288058038801, 
                     0.0220879195258021, 0.0307973567396402,0.0384510718286037,0.0480879042297602, 
                     0.0586777292191982, 0.0692614056169987, 0.080524530261755,0.0927602462470531, 
                     0.103789608925581, 0.116953168064356, 0.129253298044205, 0.141710050404072, 
                     0.156002052128315, 0.170648172497749, 0.185318425297737, 0.199463054537773, 
                     0.21351333707571, 0.22883927077055, 0.246981292963028, 0.263012766838074, 
                     0.278505563735962, 0.29365836083889, 0.310747265815735, 0.325990349054337, 
                     0.342517539858818, 0.362751632928848, 0.380199536681175, 0.39499294757843, 
                     0.414373397827148, 0.430690214037895, 0.449738144874573, 0.470167458057404, 
                     0.489019870758057, 0.507242470979691, 0.524314284324646, 0.543750524520874, 
                     0.56423419713974, 0.583679616451263, 0.601459443569183, 0.619924664497375, 
                     0.639932006597519, 0.661347180604935, 0.684117317199707, 0.704829752445221, 
                     0.725045770406723, 0.745165824890137, 0.765016138553619, 0.783461511135101, 
                     0.806382924318314, 0.829241335391998, 0.84992441534996, 0.871352434158325, 
                     0.893632233142853, 0.916052132844925, 0.938579469919205, 0.959907650947571, 
                     0.981643587350845, 1.00411677360535, 1.02836346626282, 1.05400913953781, 
                     1.07244080305099, 1.09445780515671, 1.12317627668381, 1.14943087100983, 
                     1.17091292142868, 1.19674307107925, 1.21862590312958, 1.24186837673187, 
                     1.26794159412384, 1.2907087802887, 1.31322228908539, 1.33904588222504, 
                     1.36280345916748, 1.38445019721985, 1.40972030162811, 1.43585115671158, 
                     1.45559221506119, 1.47949534654617, 1.50605195760727, 1.52572846412659, 
                     1.5493620634079, 1.5734406709671, 1.60027873516083, 1.62387949228287, 
                     1.65002930164337, 1.67236232757568, 1.70022112131119, 1.72479337453842, 
                     1.75107055902481, 1.77802211046219, 1.80302208662033, 1.83066886663437, 
                     1.85573691129684, 1.88261502981186, 1.90921849012375, 1.93813002109528, 
                     1.96372759342194, 1.99327194690704, 2.02254813909531, 2.05067992210388, 
                     2.07806444168091, 2.1041134595871, 2.13359761238098, 2.16402626037598, 
                     2.19485282897949, 2.2242579460144, 2.25219464302063, 2.27733504772186, 
                     2.30405831336975, 2.33093023300171, 2.35702276229858, 2.38648927211761, 
                     2.41750395298004, 2.44852435588837, 2.47869896888733, 2.51017570495605, 
                     2.53969788551331, 2.567915558815, 2.59746325016022, 2.62751877307892, 
                     2.65875923633575, 2.69240152835846, 2.72190320491791, 2.75302135944366, 
                     2.78631341457367, 2.8195641040802, 2.85082316398621, 2.88039410114288, 
                     2.91139125823975, 2.94296514987946, 2.97446835041046, 3.00898361206055, 
                     3.04001522064209, 3.07266867160797, 3.10598242282867),
                     y = c(0,
                           4.90024901723162, 0.160799993152722, 6.63491326258641, -1.24295055804536, 
                           1.56433744259162, -2.26590352245208, 2.20700446463354, -2.36770012911069,
                           -1.09135061899174, 0.409993989292701, -0.125972681525582, -2.41382533818026,
                           7.08902570153028, -0.759353880417294, 0.0454415959640926, -1.53496826259972,
                           6.55242014096194, -0.831256280861552, -2.50991825629084, 0.136596820654013, 
                           -1.37198445498419, -0.871298832596736, 0.663258363762466, 0.793803634291308, 
                           3.48806373666998, -4.46122081238949, 0.0871733966938564, -1.41715777257774, 
                           -0.995650815648318, 0.32155262317503, 3.14038657369241, -0.737609879885404,
                           -2.48605406511292, -3.423585843908, 0.482474753780281, -0.978538630093809, 
                           8.53596837794201, 5.48447420320695, 3.21493665820644, 3.91689160157513, 
                           4.49070195980797, 6.54104103157039, 4.80686500146557, 8.15101701282067, 
                           0.26974132191657, -0.180750068063062, 9.71812491230244, 1.54064657400204, 
                           -1.64760408795688, 4.80246028991894, 4.04215159914344, 9.37565121768513, 
                           5.33050496938428, 7.54458026088508, 6.46795470819342, 2.80960651433971, 
                           5.39216613235986, 7.20436888038562, 3.3350806460997, 8.86907069895943, 
                           1.78612988613659, 6.25550382050395, 7.60792364896564, 7.68714830528144, 
                           4.77877638957615, 12.7110501777314, -0.715628443181046, 1.64908991824022, 
                           3.03630240714679, 4.29747688442346, 1.95437780501881, 3.99869636910933, 
                           4.51794724689848, 0.933790484492299, 3.30507700050003, 3.5422970157433,
                           5.99736597322524, 0.508186860060022, 7.96616300581067, 9.94604963036295,
                           3.79083717222623, 2.57358468532258, 10.1404974171776, 13.7408303595752,
                           0.933577123801399, 9.75887417074129, 1.27693947132921, 13.4970905965787,
                           10.2087501765735, 1.68112753028756, 6.1178991508927, -0.156762622680077,
                           3.82374791691426, 4.43314678736265, 5.97907067167507, 11.3104332518482,
                           8.21426074201525, 15.320967360602, 5.81782169471483, 9.6004907412354,
                           3.40636455909704, 4.73750103921864, 3.0133019468806, 5.56595224859066,
                           12.0346332527215, -0.40283199827104, 10.5996779538754, 5.44795836991128,
                           4.70523736412729, 14.096201892183, 5.71490161813391, 3.77800720810782,
                           4.41206200639436, 4.18660847858423, 6.90788020044911, 2.78257393345915,
                           7.61717857379431, 10.2410602647684, 8.18207106836167, 4.82754943871433,
                           19.1624882857155, 16.0677109398509, 12.589708067017, 9.29079879799404,
                           7.42625019725314, 9.39025179806185, 12.6193550331438, 11.1121039747257,
                           15.7907099734986, 10.7425286789233, 7.79714300307344, 8.80608578166101,
                           17.5606266346039, 17.3088604929222, 13.4500543478523, 14.6377884248645,
                           8.07985518296064)),
                     class = "data.frame", row.names = c("layer.1",
                                                         "layer.2", "layer.3", "layer.4", "layer.5", "layer.6", "layer.7", 
                                                         "layer.8", "layer.9", "layer.10", "layer.11", "layer.12", "layer.13", 
                                                         "layer.14", "layer.15", "layer.16", "layer.17", "layer.18", "layer.19", 
                                                         "layer.20", "layer.21", "layer.22", "layer.23", "layer.24", "layer.25", 
                                                         "layer.26", "layer.27", "layer.28", "layer.29", "layer.30", "layer.31", 
                                                         "layer.32", "layer.33", "layer.34", "layer.35", "layer.36", "layer.37", 
                                                         "layer.38", "layer.39", "layer.40", "layer.41", "layer.42", "layer.43", 
                                                         "layer.44", "layer.45", "layer.46", "layer.47", "layer.48", "layer.49", 
                                                         "layer.50", "layer.51", "layer.52", "layer.53", "layer.54", "layer.55", 
                                                         "layer.56", "layer.57", "layer.58", "layer.59", "layer.60", "layer.61", 
                                                         "layer.62", "layer.63", "layer.64", "layer.65", "layer.66", "layer.67",
                                                         "layer.68", "layer.69", "layer.70", "layer.71", "layer.72", "layer.73",
                                                         "layer.74", "layer.75", "layer.76", "layer.77", "layer.78", "layer.79",
                                                         "layer.80", "layer.81", "layer.82", "layer.83", "layer.84", "layer.85",
                                                         "layer.86", "layer.87", "layer.88", "layer.89", "layer.90", "layer.91",
                                                         "layer.92", "layer.93", "layer.94", "layer.95", "layer.96", "layer.97", 
                                                         "layer.98", "layer.99", "layer.100", "layer.101", "layer.102",
                                                         "layer.103", "layer.104", "layer.105", "layer.106", "layer.107",
                                                         "layer.108", "layer.109", "layer.110", "layer.111", "layer.112",
                                                         "layer.113", "layer.114", "layer.115", "layer.116", "layer.117",
                                                         "layer.118", "layer.119", "layer.120", "layer.121", "layer.122", 
                                                         "layer.123", "layer.124", "layer.125", "layer.126", "layer.127", 
                                                         "layer.128", "layer.129", "layer.130", "layer.131", "layer.132", 
                                                         "layer.133", "layer.134", "layer.135", "layer.136", "layer.137", 
                                                         "layer.138"))

# Create scatterplot from dataframe "onepctCO2MEDIAN" with "x" and "y" variables and add "lm"
onepctCO2MEDIAN %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point() +
  xlab("x") +
  ylab("y") +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-06-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much for your response! Is it possible to condense what is in the "tribble" part? I tried just placing "onepctCO2MEDIAN", but I receive an error when doing that. Thanks

Comment: The tribble part is just me importing the data into my own session (as already noted, you should post your data (or a subset of your data) by using `dput()`). Take the last four lines (the last block with the `ggplot`code) and put `onepctCO2MEDIAN` in the place of `df` (in my example above I kept the variable names the same (`x`, `y` - note that you have named your variables the same as the arguments for `aes` (e.g. `y = y`)), but I didn't include the rownames as they are not needed for plotting the scatterplot..

Comment: Thank you, once again, for your response. I just replaced "df" with "onepctCO2MEDIAN," but I receive the same error mentioned in my previous posting. That said, I did now include in my above post the result from "dput".

Comment: Hi larsoevlisen - also, this is the error that I am receiving that prevents the regression line from appearing (the scatter plot is just fine): Warning message:
Computation failed in `stat_smooth()`:
'what' must be a function or character string

Comment: I just tried with your raw data. Look at my edit - it should work without any problem.

Comment: Hi larsoevlisen - this worked well! Thank you so, so much for your time with this!